# Add event listener per nodes level on d3 chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am still on my chart, and I need to default close the level 2 & 3 nodes, and keep the expand/collapse function on click.

Depending on the node clicked and its level, run a specific action (change color for example). My link must be a value of my data object (var pubs in my codepen) as you can see bellow (level 0 has no link, "TOOLS" in my example) :

```
{
    "name": "TOOLS",
    "children": 
      [
        {
            "name": "Localization",
            "url": "http://#",
            "children":             
                [
                   {"name": "FRANCE", "url": "http://france.fr"}
...
```

Finaly another event listener on "mouseover" to do some styling on the node (closed or open) etc...

My current code : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BqjJJv

Comment: Did you try anything, for all the features you are requesting? Or do you expect someone to do the whole implementation for you?

Comment: Yes of course, originaly it was like that https://codepen.io/fernoftheandes/pen/pcoFz

I am facing difficulties to use node in order to plug an event listener and run specific action. I also tried many things to change nodes but I don't even get how you can change theses properties using d3.select

Comment: + I've tried using this tuto https://github.com/d3/d3-selection, but don't have enough details on d3 event listener, as they redirect you on mozilla doc

Comment: So can you help me, I don't need the whole implementation, just the right tips to fix my problems

Comment: What's happening to StackOverFlow community and admins ? No more helping, only administration and no more trust between members...

Comment: I'm happy to help when I have some time. Right now, I do not have time to do some unpaid work, especially when the requirements are not clear.

Comment: I got it, but the goal of this website is to help each other beyond the money. Another thing that could have been useful is your comment about the requirements, more than the first comment you made which is not constructive. Finally I started a bounty, so it is quite clear that I pay with points. If you are looking for money there are many website to make some 

Comment: It's easy enough to add an event listener to the nodes -- is that all you want so that you can fill in the actions yourself? The data structure in the code pen doesn't have any links in it so there's nothing that can be done about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to collapse all nodes except the root and the first set of children, you can run the following code:

```
root.children.forEach(collapse);
```

This recursively applies the `collapse` function to all the children of the root.

There is already a click event listener on your nodes, which you can alter according to your plans. Adding listeners for mouseover and mouseout events is very simple:

```
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "node")
.on("click", click)
.on('mouseover', mouseover) // mouseover!
.on('mouseout', mouseout)   // mouseout!
```

You then need to add functions that will define the actions that occur. Here are a couple of sample functions:

```
// `d` is the data item attached to the DOM node;
// `this` is the node that triggered the event (`g.node`)
function mouseover(d) {
  // select the `rect` node that is the child of the DOM node that triggered the event
  d3.select(this).select('rect').style('fill', function(d){
    // depending on the level of the node, give it one of these tacky colours
    if (d.depth === 0) {
      return 'deepskyblue'
    } else if (d.depth === 1) {
      return 'deeppink'
    } else if (d.depth === 2) {
      return 'goldenrod'
    }
    return 'papayawhip' // default
  })
}

function mouseout(d) {
  // select the rect element
  d3.select(this).select('rect')
    // if the node has collapsed children, turn it light blue; otherwise turn it red
    .style('fill', d => d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "red")
}
```

You can also add extra functionality to the `click` function in a similar manner.

Here are the event listeners in action:

```js
var pubs = {
  "name": "TOOLS",
  "children": [{
      "name": "Localization",
      "children": [{
          "name": "FRANCE"
        },
        {
          "name": "SUISSE"
        },
        {
          "name": "USA"
        },
        {
          "name": "UK"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Test",
      "children": [{
          "name": "FRANCE"
        },
        {
          "name": "SUISSE"
        },
        {
          "name": "USA"
        },
        {
          "name": "UK"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Oh My God",
      "children": [{
          "name": "FRANCE"
        },
        {
          "name": "SUISSE"
        },
        {
          "name": "USA"
        },
        {
          "name": "UK"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Another Tool",
      "children": [{
          "name": "FRANCE"
        },
        {
          "name": "SUISSE"
        },
        {
          "name": "USA"
        },
        {
          "name": "UK"
        }
      ]
    },

    {
      "name": "And Again",
      "children": [{
          "name": "FRANCE"
        },
        {
          "name": "SUISSE"
        },
        {
          "name": "USA"
        },
        {
          "name": "UK"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "And Again",
      "children": [{
          "name": "FRANCE"
        },
        {
          "name": "SUISSE"
        },
        {
          "name": "USA"
        },
        {
          "name": "UK"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Production",
      "children": [{
          "name": "FRANCE"
        },
        {
          "name": "SUISSE"
        },
        {
          "name": "USA"
        },
        {
          "name": "UK"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Audio",
      "children": [{
          "name": "AUT-11"
        },
        {
          "name": "AUT-12"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Animation",
      "children": [{
          "name": "AUT-11"
        },
        {
          "name": "AUT-12"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Tags",
      "children": [{
          "name": "AUT-11"
        },
        {
          "name": "AUT-12"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

var diameter = 800;

var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 120,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 120
  },
  width = diameter,
  height = diameter;

var i = 0,
  duration = 350,
  root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
  .size([360, diameter / 2 - 80])
  .separation(function(a, b) {
    return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 1) / a.depth;
  });


var diagonal_extras = {
  path: {
    // diagonal line
    direct: function(p) {
        return [p.source, p.target];
      }

      // this is also the default path in radial trees
      ,
    l_shape: function(p) {
        return [p.source, {
          x: p.target.x,
          y: p.source.y
        }, p.target];
      }

      ,
    l_shape_2: function(p) {
        return [p.source, {
          x: p.source.x,
          y: p.target.y
        }, p.target];
      }

      ,
    dogleg: function(p) {
        return [p.source,
          {
            x: p.source.x,
            y: (p.source.y + p.target.y) / 2
          },
          {
            x: (p.source.x + p.target.x) / 2,
            y: (p.source.y + p.target.y) / 2
          },
          {
            x: p.target.x,
            y: (p.source.y + p.target.y) / 2
          },
          p.target
        ];
      }

      ,
    dogleg_2: function(p) {
      return [p.source,
        {
          x: (p.source.x + p.target.x) / 2,
          y: p.source.y
        },
        {
          x: (p.source.x + p.target.x) / 2,
          y: (p.source.y + p.target.y) / 2
        },
        {
          x: (p.source.x + p.target.x) / 2,
          y: p.target.y
        },
        p.target
      ];
    }

  }

  ,
  polar_obj_to_cart: function(pt) {
      var angle = pt.x / 180 * Math.PI;
      return [pt.y * Math.cos(angle), pt.y * Math.sin(angle)];
    }

    ,
  polar_coords_to_cart: function(xy) {
    var angle = xy[0] / 180 * Math.PI;
    return [xy[1] * Math.cos(angle), xy[1] * Math.sin(angle)];
  }

}

diagonal_extras.right_angle = function() {

  var projection = d3.svg.diagonal().projection(),
    path_type = 'dogleg';

  function diagonal(d) {
    return diagonal.path_maker(diagonal_extras.path[diagonal.path_type()](d));
  }

  diagonal.path_maker = function(pathData) {
    return "M" + pathData.map(projection).join(' ');
  };

  diagonal.valid_path_types = function() {
    return Object.keys(diagonal_extras.path);
  };

  diagonal.path_type = function(x) {
    if (!arguments.length) {
      return path_type;
    }
    if (diagonal_extras.path[x]) {
      path_type = x;
      return diagonal;
    }
    throw new Error(x + ' is not a valid path type');
  };

  diagonal.projection = function(x) {
    if (!arguments.length) {
      return projection;
    }
    projection = x;
    return diagonal;
  };

  diagonal.path = function(x) {
    if (!arguments.length) {
      return path;
    }
    path = x;
    return diagonal;
  };

  diagonal.draw = function(d) {
    return diagonal(d);
  };

  return diagonal;
}
diagonal_extras.radial = function() {
  var diagonal = diagonal_extras.right_angle(),
    projection = function(pt) {
      return [pt.x, pt.y];
    };

  diagonal.path_type('direct');

  diagonal.projection = function(x) {
    if (!arguments.length) {
      return projection;
    }
    projection = x;
    return diagonal;
  };

  diagonal.path_maker = function(pathData) {

    var projected = pathData.map(function(x) {
        return projection(x);
      }),
      pl = projected.length,
      points, prev_angle;

    // direct link:
    if (2 === pl) {
      return 'M' + projected.map(function(x) {
        return diagonal_extras.polar_coords_to_cart(x);
      }).join(' ');
    }

    points = projected.map(function(obj) {
      return {
        angle: obj[0] / 180 * Math.PI,
        radius: obj[1]
      };
    });

    return "M" + points.map(function(pt) {
      var str = '';
      if (prev_angle) {
        if (prev_angle === pt.angle) {
          // draw a straight line
          str = 'L';
        } else {
          // draw an arc to the new radius and angle
          str = 'A' + pt.radius + ',' + pt.radius
            // x axis rotation
            +
            " 0 "
            // large arc flag
            +
            " 0,"
            // sweep
            +
            (pt.angle > prev_angle ? 1 : 0) + " ";

        }
      }
      prev_angle = pt.angle;
      return str + pt.radius * Math.cos(pt.angle) + "," + pt.radius * Math.sin(pt.angle);

    }).join(' ');

  };
  return diagonal;
}

var diagonal = diagonal_extras.radial()
  .path_type('dogleg')
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.x - 90, d.y];
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")");

var rect = {
  l: 95,
  w: 20
}

root = pubs;
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

root.children.forEach(collapse); // start with all children collapsed
update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root),
    links = tree.links(nodes),
    offset = nodes[0].x;
  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = d.depth * 150;
  });

  // Normalise angles so that the root is horizontal
  if (nodes[0].x > 180) {
    nodes[0].x = nodes[0].x - 90
  } else {
    nodes[0].x = nodes[0].x + 90
  }
  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    //.attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")"; })
    .on("click", click)
    .on('mouseover', mouseover)
    .on('mouseout', mouseout)

  nodeEnter.append("rect")
    .attr("width", rect.l)
    .attr("height", rect.w)
    .attr("x", -rect.l / 2)
    .attr("y", -rect.w / 2)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "red";
    });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    //.attr("transform", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "translate(0)" : "rotate(180)translate(-" + (d.name.length * 8.5)  + ")"; })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    })
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")";
    })

  // nodeUpdate.select("circle")
  //     .attr("r", 4.5)
  //     .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return d.x < 180 ? "translate(0)" : "rotate(180)";
    });

  // TODO: appropriate transform
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    //.attr("transform", function(d) { return "diagonal(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
    .remove();

  // nodeExit.select("circle")
  //     .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.target.id;
    });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x0,
        y: source.y0
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      return diagonal({
        source: {
          x: d.source.x,
          y: d.source.y + rect.l / 2
        },
        target: {
          x: d.target.x,
          y: d.target.y - rect.l / 2
        }
      })
    });

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

function mouseover(d) {
  d3.select(this).select('rect').style('fill', function(d){
    if (d.depth === 0) {
      return 'deepskyblue'
    } else if (d.depth === 1) {
      return 'deeppink'
    } else if (d.depth === 2) {
      return 'goldenrod'
    }
    return 'papayawhip'
  })
}

function mouseout(d) {
  d3.select(this).select('rect').style('fill', d => d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "red")
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }

  update(d);
}

// Collapse nodes
function collapse(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d._children.forEach(collapse);
    d.children = null;
  }
}
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ahah that's funny because I just write a similar code and it works quite well, as you say, you need to use the depth to know which node level you are entering in, and depending on that my click function return different color :) Let me try your code and i'll get back to you ;) and yes I just realized that my click function was an event listener -_-" Thanks just need to check with what your shared

Comment: Ok I kept the answer from HelgeBox to have children closed it's easy to implement and it works well. For the event listener I took your example and it's exactly what I wanted to do :) Now I can open my link and so on thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is for the levels 2 and 3 to be closed by default you could just rename every `children` property to `_children` in the `pubs` object. Like you already do in your click handler, only start out with underscored children and that's it. For your other questions, I have no answer yet.

Like this:

```
{
    "name": "TOOLS",
    "_children": 
      [
        {
            "name": "Localization",
            "url": "http://#",
            "_children":             
                [
                   {"name": "FRANCE", "url": "http://france.fr"}
...
```